# JsTree - Keep Parents Open

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using [Jstree](http://www.jstree.com/).  I have a about 10 top-level items, all with various levels of children.  I want to keep the Top Level items open, always.

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, even when someone clicks these items, I want them to stay open

I imagine someonething needs to go in this step of my code, Im just not sure exactly what:

```
.delegate(".jstree-open>a", "click.jstree", function(event){
      $.jstree._reference(this).close_node(this,false,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HLhys/

You need to set this option:

```
"initially_open": ["menu_2","menu_8"]
```

Set as many id's you want.

Use .reopen() on jsTreen instance if you want them to stay opened in case of node changes (or other actions ...). This method will reopen all nodes mentioned in initially_open array.

Comment: and will they remain open even if someone clicks them?  I don't think this will solve that, right?

Comment: If you want them to stay that way after further call .reopen() on jstree object. Reopen will open all nodes mentioned in attribute initially_open.

Comment: unfortunately, due to the way things are setup, I can't rely on initially open, because I use that to remember states when I go to other pages.  Is there not a way to use my code above, and have a line that says "if this is a top level item, don't close it"?